# how to display plain text with html tags as HTML content in jsp pages

Tags: html, css, mysql, jsp, jstl

I have the text of data with HTML tags

I need to display the data in JSP from the database,

when I retrieve that data from the database its appear as plain text and not displaying respective CSS

I need to display the data with the respective CSS effect, how can I do that..

for retrieving data I'm using JSTL tags.

[data in my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvds0.png)

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to display the data?

Comment: <c:forEach var="exs" items="${EQS}">
    <c:out value="${exs.para}" />
  </c:forEach>

Comment: where is your `html` `jsp` `css` code

Comment: Not familiar with JSP, but https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_out_tag.htm says you can use the attribute `escapeXml="false"` in the `<c:out>` element to prevent showing it as plain text.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.